# Analytics event tracking tag stopped working

Tags: google-analytics, analytics

I don't understand event tracking tags very well. My tag was working fine, but then it stopped registering new events.

Can somebody, please, take a look at my code?

www.ahseamodapega.com.br

It would be the first banner on the sidebar!

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You are using "curly" single quotes in your event tracking call, replace them with 'straight' quotes.

[image]